Is there a problem known to have no fastest algorithm, up to polynomials?
Is there a problem where for all correct algorithms $A$, letting $T(n)$ be the runtime of $A$, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ and a correct algorithm $A'$ running in time $T(n)\cdot n^{-\varepsilon}$?
This could happen, for example, if for all $k$ there is an algorithm running in time $O(n^{1+1/k})$, but the function $f(k)$ that outputs the source code of the $k^{th}$ algorithm in the sequence is uncomputable.
I'm fine with a very artificial problem that provably has this property, I don't need it to be "natural."  I'm most interested if we can name an explicit problem, with an unconditional proof that it has this property.  But failing that, existential results or proofs using standard assumptions from complexity theory are interesting as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%27s_speedup_theorem

Thanks Emil!  I didn't know that theorem, and it seems to answer the question perfectly.

@GMB This older question of mine is similar to what you're asking, with the caveat that "running time" is replaced with the number of comparisons needed to solve a problem, so there is no Turing Machine in sight. It is more of an information theory problem. But maybe you will find my answer interesting, since there is a naturally occurring example of speedup. :-)

Cool - thanks for the reference!

The answer is yes even for the $O(n^{1+1/k})$ complexities your mention. The proof is somewhat analogous to Blum's speedup theorem proof; see my question and answer Does $∩_{ε>0} \mathrm{DTIME}(O(n^{2+ε})) = \mathrm{DTIME}(n^{2+o(1)})$?

This is essentially true for matrix multiplication, as shown in this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4568320.
The "essentially" is because what they actually show is that this is true for all tensor-decomposition-based algorithms for MM. The MM exponent $\omega$ is defined in terms of tensor rank and as far as I know all known generic MM algorithms (Strassen, Coppersmith-Winograd, improvements to CW from the last 10 years) use this framework. So, I think it's typically taken for granted that MM algorithms will use the framework. Nevertheless, I don't know of an argument that any algorithm for MM must use tensor decomposition, although maybe there is a simple one. Hopefully someone more familiar with this can weigh in.

Thanks Huck - I didn't know this was proved, and that's a very nice example of a natural function that (conditionally) does the job.

It is not known that all such MM algorithms must be bilinear - Turing machines can do all sorts of things that aren't algebraically meaningful. But this is still a great theorem, at the very least in the flavor of the question!
